# How to change toolbar style programmatically? When I try to do this popup menu changes instead of the toolbar

Tags: java, android

I have a custom toolbar for my app, but in one of the activities I want to change the style of the toolbar programatically. This is the style for the toolbar that I want to apply programmatically.

```
<style name="toolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:background">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I use this code to change toolbar style programmatically

```
toolbar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.toolbarStyle);
```

The problem is, the popup theme changes instead of the toolbar.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code:

```
toolbar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.toolbarStyle);
```

set's the theme on the entire `Activity`, because you've called `setTheme()` on the `Activity`'s `Context`.

A theme is intended to be for an entire application, not just for an individual UI element. You want to use styling to style just this one UI element.

If you have a custom toolbar, then you should just create methods on your custom toolbar to adjust these styles and call those methods from your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in activity or fragment?
If activity, try
getSupportActionBar() to get the toolbar used

Comment: I am in activity. It's the same even I use getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext().setTheme(androidx.appcompat.R.style.Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Light);
the changes happen to OverflowMenu popup theme.